# ionic4 base64 native plugin not working in android target sdk 29

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

In my ionic app i integrated ionic4 native base64 plugin, it was working fine in all android os mobiles when my android target sdk 28. due to play store restriction i have changed tragetSDK 28 to 29 then it is not working in android os 10 mobile. please can any one help how to fix it.

Comment: please check your compile sdk version too .. might be a case it not get updated with target version

Comment: compile sdk also 29.when compile sdk 29 and target sdk 28 it is working  but when compile sdk 29 and target sdk 29 it is not work

Answer (score 2):

In Android, in the `build.gradle(app)` file, change target SDK to `targetSdkVersion 30` or `targetSdkVersion 29`.

Then go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add this line `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`  in the `application` tag like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Comment: @Shinichi Kudo You saved the day!! thanks a lot!! it really worked !